# Flutter [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

Tags: flutter, http, post, error-handling

In my application I am trying to login user through API, but I am getting the following error.

```
E/flutter (14103): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (14103): <!DOCTYPE html>
E/flutter (14103): ^
E/flutter (14103): 
E/flutter (14103): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1404:5)
E/flutter (14103): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1271:9)
E/flutter (14103): #2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:936:22)
E/flutter (14103): #3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10)
E/flutter (14103): #4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:505:36)
E/flutter (14103): #5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:156:41)
E/flutter (14103): #6      jsonDecode (dart:convert/json.dart:96:10)
E/flutter (14103): #7      FormBloc.login (package:curtain/blocs/form_bloc.dart:74:18)
```

In my previous version of code everything was working successfully. After I did some modifications (including adding validators) is my code not working.
Below you can see my http request:

```
static Future<dynamic> loginUser(String username, String password) async {
    final result = await http.post('$baseURL/en/users/login/', headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    }, body: {
      'username': username,
      'password': password,
    });

    return result?.body;
  }
```

And this is how I am calling it:

```
dynamic login(BuildContext context) async {
    final res = await AuthService.loginUser(_username.value, _password.value);
    final data = jsonDecode(res) as Map<String, dynamic>;

    if (data['status'] != 200) {
      addError(data['message']);
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        CupertinoPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => FeedScreen(),
        ),
      );
      return res;
    }
```

let me know if you need to see how my json response should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see there is nothing wrong with the code. Either you are accessing a **`wrong URL`** or there's something wrong with the **web service**. Please ensure the URL and see if you are accessing the correct URL.

Try to hit this api in **Postman** and see the response you are getting. You will get better understanding.

Comment: That is the thing. It is working in Postman. It is working when I am logging in through the URL itself as well. But here errors.

Comment: Could it be because I am not using Strings for username and password, but  `BehaviorSubject<String>()` ??

Comment: Before http.post() ensure the data which you are passing as values i.e username and password in Log

Comment: Yeah, I printed the data before http.post(), they are correct. However, it is giving the above error just after those printed values

Comment: Yes, I found it. When I defined the baseURL I added slash (/) in the end. And here when I was calling it `http.post('$baseURL/en/users/login/')` I added another slash, which was not needed. Thank you.